# IBM Watson Speech to Text Websocket closing (with code 1000) without result

Tags: node.js, websocket, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I try to consume basic Speech-To-Text service through websocket using [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package. But after successfully open the connection and send initial message, I never get the `listening` state. 
I also try to send the audio and empty binary (to indicate that uploading process is done), but the server always return `close` with code `1000`.

Following is my code

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var WS = require('ws');

var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=[TOKEN]&model=en-UK_NarrowbandModell&x-watson-learning-opt-out=1';
var getTokenForm = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://[USER_ID]:[PASSWORD]@stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api',
};
var filepath = 'C:/Temp/test1.wav';

request(getTokenForm, function(error, response, body) {
  wsURI = wsURI.replace('[TOKEN]', body);
  var message = {
    'action': 'start',
    'content-type': 'audio/wav',
    'continuous': true,
    'inactivity_timeout': -1
  };
  var ws = new WS(wsURI);

  ['message', 'error', 'close', 'open', 'connection'].forEach(function(eventName) {
    ws.on(eventName, console.log.bind(console, eventName + ' event: '));
  });

  ws.on('open', function(evt) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    setTimeout(function timeout() {
      var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
      readStream.on('data', function(data) {
        ws.send(data, {
          binary: true,
          mask: false,
        });
      });

      readStream.on('end', function() {
        ws.send(new Buffer(0), {
          binary: true,
          mask: false,
        });
      });
    }, 1000);
  });

  ws.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

Also try to send the file directly (without the stream).

```
var sound = fs.readFileSync(filepath);
ws.send(sound, { binary: true, mask: false});
```

And try to add custom header `Authorization`

```
var authorization = 'Basic ' + new Buffer('USER_ID:PASSWORD').toString('base64');
var ws = new WS(wsURI, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authorization,
    }
});
```

But no luck so far.

Comment: I can get the result successfully with [code example from node sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/dev/examples/speech_to_text.v1.js), but I would like to see it work without the official SDK.

Comment: there is a reason for SDKs after all

Comment: There is also another sdk if you want to use speech to text in the browser. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of things here. The main issue is that the model in the querystring has a typo - there should be only one 'l' on the end. (Although, not responding with an error message is a bug in the service that I'm going to report to the team.)

So, fix that and you get an error that frames should be masked. That's an easy fix, just switch `mask: false` to `true` in both places.

Then, once you've finished sending your audio & ending message, the service will send your final results and then another `{"state": "listening"}` message. This second `state: listening` should be your trigger to close the connection. Otherwise it will eventually timeout and close automatically (`inactivity_timeout` applies when you're sending audio with no speech in it, not when you aren't sending any data at all.)

Comment: Update: the team is aware of the issue with invalid model names and is currently working on a resolution.